# How to snap faces of two objects perfectly

Tags: snapping

I'm trying to align the "rope handles" foot to the plank, so that the two faces are perfectly aligned, I believe its called.  This is tricky because there might be answers in forums but I really don't understand if they are relevant, outdated or too explained poorly. I'm disappointed that the Snap-Face doesn't do it for me but I guess its doesn't snap to a face FROM a face. Well I guess it does but only if I select the bottom face in Edit mode.

Note that the bridge is an Array of 1 plank following a Path/Curve and the Array modifier has not yet been applied.

[image]

Comment: This may be hard to explain but I'll try to explain how I'd do it..
0. ALWAYS save before following advice, in case it doesn't work out for you.
1. Make a copy of the plank, without the array modifier.
2. Cut the square area into it using ruler/knife whichever you feel works better for you
3. Select that new face, press CTRL+I to invert selection and delete inverted selection
4. Extrude the face you created/have left. This way it'll be at the angle you need it to be
5. Now connect that to your rope as the new handle and see if that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recreated your issue: select the foot object, go to edit mode, selct the bottom face you want to be aligned, press Shift S > cursor to selected. Back in object mode right click and choose "Set origin to 3D cursor".

Now you can activate the face snapping otpion, ticking "Align rotation to target", and easily place your objects.

[image]

Working on your file I did 4 actions:

1. enable affect rotate in the face snap options (so that the snapping acts even when manually rotating the object)
2. Applied scale of your foot object (Ctrl A)
3. The most important: selecting a foot and pressing Alt G, Alt S, Alt R resets the object's transforms: in its rest position the object has to be in the center of the world (0,0,0), with no rot (0,0,0) and with unity scale (1,1,1).
4. Untick this transform option that make your object locked on rotations.

[image]

In this state your object wasn't straight and centered. The face snap acts on the whole object, based on its origin; you can think the of the origin as a ghost vertex which is parent to all the others vertices. Snapping gives to the origin the loc and  rot of the underlying face, and this is reflected to the whole object, if this object is straight vertical in rest position.

So you have to change your object in edit mode so that it fits the requirements (as in photo quad view).

At this point simply move (G) and duplicate (Shift D) with the face snapping option to easily place the feet.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Easy explanation to follow but I dont get any results at all almost, maybe I have some other setting activated elsewhere. I haven't really changed a lot much though since Im beginner level.
https://imgur.com/a/viHoi9X
Pic 1 I tried on the same plank, I couldn't get a better result.
Pic 2 I tried the plank to the left and as you see it looks as if my rotation is locked. The foot never rotates. 
I used the exact settings from your photo.

Comment: The results above are if I activate array and curve modifier. if I DO NOT, then it looks like this https://imgur.com/a/MutXTnS
Actually I uploaded the blend and blend1 file here https://www.filemail.com/d/vvlaeldplxpuxvl if maybe its easier.

Comment: I think you'd better upload your blend file, to see what's causing the issue https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Ok I just edited my above comment :P Ill link again - https://www.filemail.com/d/vvlaeldplxpuxvl thanks for your time

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: ok thanks interesting, some of the theory there is new or ive not done practically enough of it yet.
Will mark finished in about a days time when ive got a bit more time to fiddle.

Comment: Sorry but thing just doesnt work for me.
First off I cant rotate the object in object or edit mode, no idea why. Never happened before.
And if I reset location and rotation to zeros the object is still tilted. I just dont get this.
sorry that im wasting your time. i wish it wasnt this bothersome for such a simple thing.

Comment: Also I dont understand what you mean by "So you have to change your object in edit mode so that it fits the requirements (as in photo quad view)." because its not possible to change the loc and rot in Edit mode.

heres my tilted object: https://i.imgur.com/mPDVwZJ.jpg

Comment: I also dont know what keybinds you refer to with Ctrl G, Ctrl S, Ctrl R . Because by standard ctrl+s is used to Save. My guess is you mean the equivalent of Apply->All Transform?

Comment: My fault: It was Alt G, Alt R, Alt S, which simply bring loc rot and scale to reset (000, 000, 111). Then I forgot to mention that you had activated the option "Affect only Location" in the "N" toolbar, which probably is causing your headache. To reset the tilt you can do it in two (exactly equivalent) ways: one is rotating all the vertices in edit mode, the second is rotating in object mode, then applying the rotation (Ctrl A).

Comment: To fully understand the difference between Applying (Ctrl A) and resetting (Alt G Alt R ALt S) make this experiment: move, rotate and scale the default cube (which consist in 8 vertices + one object origin). Then try the two options (Applying or resetting), checking the relation between the origin and the 8 vertices. When you read the loc rot and scale values of an object, they are related to its origin, no matter where the actual vertices are, and so do all functions like snapping.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am unable to make the face snap. I also can't rotate in Object mode. Im clueless.  I think I've had enough because I really dont understand this. thanks again but I will put this on ice sadly.

Comment: Did you untick the "Affect only location" preference in the "N" Panel?

Comment: Ok yes I did. from the screenshot I saw Location was [V]. It seems i can do this now. very clutch. 
I will continue to study the alt keybinds, because I think I thought Apply Transformation was the same thing. While rotating back the pole to straight and alt-r brain clicked a little more.  i can now continue and be happy.